# PL/SQL update all records except with max value

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Please help with SQL query. I've got a table:

```
CREATE TABLE PCDEVUSER.tabletest
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR2(64),
    pattern INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    tempval INT
);
```

Let's pretend it was filled with values:

```
INSERT INTO TABLETEST (ID, NAME, PATTERN, TEMPVAL) VALUES (1, 'A', 1, 10);
INSERT INTO TABLETEST (ID, NAME, PATTERN, TEMPVAL) VALUES (2, 'A', 1, 20);
INSERT INTO TABLETEST (ID, NAME, PATTERN, TEMPVAL) VALUES (3, 'A', 2, 10);
INSERT INTO TABLETEST (ID, NAME, PATTERN, TEMPVAL) VALUES (5, 'A', 2, 20);
INSERT INTO TABLETEST (ID, NAME, PATTERN, TEMPVAL) VALUES (4, 'A', 2, 30);
```

And I need to update all records (grouped by pattern) with NO MAX value TEMPVALUE. So as result I have to update records with Ids (1, 3, 5). Records with IDs (2, 4) has max values in there PATTERN group.

HELP PLZ

Comment: What value do you want to update them with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This select statement will help you get the IDs you need :

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 (SELECT
   id
  ,name
  ,pattern
  ,tempval
  ,MAX(tempval) OVER (PARTITION BY pattern)  max_tempval
  FROM
   tabletest
 )
WHERE 1=1
AND tempval != max_tempval
;
```

You should be able to build an update statement around that easily enough

Comment: thank you man. One more time I see the 'OVER (PARTITION BY pattern)' construction. Maybe you can tell me where to learn it better - I can't understand it :(

Comment: @R1K0 : Just search for Oracle Analytic functions - there's loads of good stuff out there.

Comment: And man - what about '1=1' condition - or it just after using visual SQL? :)

Comment: That's just habit - I always put that condition in.  It's because I often want to comment out lines in a where clause.  If the first line (WHERE...)  is meaningful then if you want to comment that out you need to move the WHERE statement down to the next line.  If the first line is WHERE 1=1 I know I'll never want to comment that line.

Comment: Nice idea. Start to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
update tabletest t
    set ????
    where t.tempval < (select max(tempval) from tabletest tt where tt.pattern = t.pattern);
```

It is unclear what values you want to set.  The `????` is for the code that sets the values.